# Google Analytics Shows Visits without even Installing the code on the website

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Something strange is happening to my Google Analytics Account and I don't understand it.

A while ago I created a Google Analytics account for my website, after mandatory fields completions, I received Tracking code and was instructed to place it on my website.

Due to some other important work, I never got around to adding it on the website.

Now I just went and checked my Google Analytics Account and it shows the Nine (9) visits from Russia (same country with same ip)on the 21st Jan 2015. This is really wired.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how I can fix this.  I just create an analytics account and leave it alone for 20 days. Maybe you will notice visits as well.

Comment: its spam data, automatically inserted into your account by different websites.

Comment: Thnx,DalmTo I knew it, but how it shows in the analytics?

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to a lot of people recently.   What nomrally happends is that they get your web property id by checking the source on your website `UA-45053583-1` then they can  manually insert data into your Google Analytics account using the [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).   They don't actually need to visit your website to insert bogus data.

There is a huge list of sites that do this.  The current term for this is called `Referral Spam`.

Now what I agree is strange is you say you never put the JavaScript tracking code on your website.  This makes me wonder how they managed to find your web property id in the first place.   So I just sent this question in an email off to someone on the Google Analytics team asking them what's up.

I will reply to this if I hear anything back from them.

Update: I posted this question over to the [Google+ comunity](https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346/posts/8vew3m6ayZs) it is possible that these spammers have started just spamming every possible web property.  It would be possible to just loop though everything and they just happen to have hit yours.

Comment: Yes, its really really strange . Thank you for feedback

Answer (score 1):

There have been similar reports by other users:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/what-are-these-unknown-visits-to-my-private-unlisted-webpage

What these spammers are doing is to target random property IDs. For more background information:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/21/referrer-spam.html

Answer (score 0):

It is spam, coming from referrals and organic as well. If you look it up closely, you'd see that most of the traffic is coming from Russia and Ukraine.

If you want to filter the traffic do it at a country level. Filtering it at a domain/ip level won't solve the issue due that they constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

[cross-posted to the Google+ group]
A lot of people assume this is rampant because a number of site redirects have been involved (darodar/econom/ilovevitaly/blackhatworth/cenoval/...) and even some search spam (resellerclub scam, google officially -recommends...) .

Actually it is all one person (Vitaly Popav took credit and owns the sites; hence iLoveVitaly). If you check the Count of Sessions dimension, you will see they are all sequential. Because of Google's last-non-direct attribution, some may actually have been direct visits, making the attack even harder to detect. I think he's using an emulated client to push millions of clicks into GA, and he rotates and takes a break every few days so people think their filters and blocking were effective. I have several test properties that have never been used yet get spam, and they are all -1 properties.

Yes, they are hitting ID numbers at random, but the followup is more directed: the initial darodar (and now cenoval) links had forum####### in their urls, and those numbers were your Google tracking id numbers. If you clicked on it, they discovered they hit a real one and you got more. C'mon, I KNOW you clicked :-)

I too was thinking the custom dimension on the web site, but really, just filtering to include valid hostnames is enough. Any more than that, they need to be targeting you, and if they are targeting you, nothing would stop them -- all valid visits come from a visitor's browser, and you have no control over that endpoint. It can be spoofed.

ref: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/